# Perl idiom for quickly searching file with elements in array

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, grep

what is the Perl idiom to search a string or a whole file for array elements occurrences? E.g.:

```
my @array = qw(word, test, ...);
my $string = ".......";
```

I want to search for `word` or `test` (can also be `words`, `tester`, etc.) inside `$string` and return whatever is found (i.e. group match).

I searched the docs, seems like `map + grep` is what I need but I just can’t come up with the code for it. Perl is such fun that I am totally clueless sometimes. :)

Using one example from `map`:

```
my @squares = map { $_ * $_ } grep { $_ > 5 } @numbers;
```

I suppose I can split the string into array and `grep`. Am I right?

```
grep { @array } @string;  # something like grep {/(word|test)/} @string but I want to use array
```

Comment: show full sample input and output

Comment: hi, works simlar to Python's str.startswith. thanks

Comment: @dorothy OK, so “word” should not match in “I like crosswords” and should match in “Let’s play with words”. Should the group capture “word” or “words”?

Comment: just anything like word*

Answer (score 6):

```
my @word_roots = qw( word test );

my $pat = join '|', map quotemeta, @word_roots;
my $re = qr/\b(?:$pat)\w+\b/;

my @matches = $string =~ /($re)/g;
```

Comment: thanks. can you explain quotemeta and where i can find this info. thanks.

Comment: @dorothy [`perldoc -f quotemeta`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html) It escapes characters that are special inside regular expressions.

Comment: It converts text into a regex pattern that matches that text.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this from a **[re.pl](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Devel-REPL-1.003025/lib/Devel/REPL.pm)** session:

```
$ my @array = qw(word test)
$VAR1 = 'word';
$VAR2 = 'test';

$ my $string = ' the word is test, I said'
 the word is test, I said

$ my @match_array = map { $string =~ /\b($_)\b/ } @array
$VAR1 = 'word';
$VAR2 = 'test';
```

The parenthesis around `\b$_\b` capture the match in the regex inside of `map`.

The `\b` ensures that we only match is the word is found on its own (like "test" or "word") and not words that contain the characters "test", or "word" in them like "coward" or "brightest". See http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html for more details on `\b`.

Comment: fantastic. i will try that out.

Comment: Be aware that this will also match partially, e.g. "tested" will match.

Comment: @TLP, yes that's no problem. I wish to match all starting with "test"*

Comment: Beware: this will also match 'smartest' and 'brightest'; if you need to anchor to the start of a word, use the `\b` (word boundary) marker.